# Testing the Response of a PUT Method (or an response really)

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a `PUT` method that I am attempting to test, but, like usual, APEX's ridiculous restrictions are causing roadblocks at every turn I make. My put method works fine when I am calling it from Postman or some live client, but I need to write some tests in SF for the class before going to production.

In my tests, I would like to test what happens in the response. Did it respond with a 200 status code? Did it respond with the correct error? etc. But for some APEX reason it doesn't allow me to return `HttpResponse`, and I can't figure out how I can write the test to actually test the response.

Here is my PUT method:

```
@HttpPut
global static void updateStudentRoleRelationships() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

    try {
        // Get Request
        Map<String, Object> requestBody = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.requestBody.toString());

        System.debug(requestBody);

        // Parse request body
        List<Object> newRoleIds = (List<Object>)requestBody.get('roles');
        Integer studentId = Integer.valueOf(requestBody.get('studentId'));

        // Check request body
        String errorString = '';
        Boolean errored = false;
        if (studentId == null) {
            errorString += '\'studentId\' not provided\n';
            errored = true;
        }
        if (errored) {
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(errorString);
            res.statusCode = 422;
        }

        // Query db for needed data
        Student__c student = [SELECT Id FROM Student__c WHERE drupalId__c = :studentId];
        List<Role__c> allRoles = [SELECT Id, drupalId__c FROM Role__c];

        // Delete Previous records
        delete [SELECT Id, Role__c FROM StudentRoleRelationship__c WHERE Student__c = :student.Id];

        // Create new records
        List<StudentRoleRelationship__c> newRelationships = new List<StudentRoleRelationship__c>();
        for (Object newRoleId : newRoleIds) {
            for (Role__c role : allRoles) {
                if ((Integer)newRoleId == role.drupalId__c) {
                    StudentRoleRelationship__c studentRoleRelationship = new StudentRoleRelationship__c();
                    studentRoleRelationship.Role__c = role.Id;
                    studentRoleRelationship.Student__c = student.Id;
                    insert studentRoleRelationship;
                    newRelationships.add(studentRoleRelationship);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Add Response
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(String.valueOf(newRelationships));
        res.statusCode = 200;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Error
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());
        res.statusCode = 500;
    }
}
```

Here is my test method:

```
/**
 * SET UP
 */
@testSetup
static void setup() {
    prepareDatabase();
}

/**
 * UpdateStudentRoles
 */
public class UpdateBody {
    public String studentId;
    public List<Integer> roles;
}

public class MockUpdateStudentRolesHttpResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        return res;
    }
}

@isTest
static void put_updateStudentRoleRelationships() {

    // Get and set the needed information
    List<Student__c> studentRecs = [SELECT id FROM Student__c LIMIT 1];
    List<Role__c> roleRecs = [SELECT drupalId__c FROM Role__c LIMIT 1];
    String studentId = studentRecs[0].Id;
    Integer roleId = (Integer)roleRecs[0].drupalId__c;

    // Prepare Request  
    RestRequest req  = new RestRequest();
    RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

    req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/YTPStudentRolesController';
    req.httpMethod = 'PUT';

    UpdateBody body = new UpdateBody();
    body.studentId = studentRecs[0].Id;
    body.roles = new List<Integer>();
    body.roles.add(roleId);
    String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(body);
    req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(jsonBody);

    RestContext.request = req;
    RestContext.response = res;

    // Test
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockUpdateStudentRolesHttpResponse());
    api_YTPStudentRolesController.updateStudentRoleRelationships();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Right now, this test returns as successful even though the response returns with an error. How can I actually run Asserts on the response from a put method?!?!

Answer (score 2):

Test the method by calling it directly, not using a callout. Make sure you set the `RestContext` variables as they will be null otherwise.

```
RestContext.request = new RestRequest();
RestContext.response = new RestResponse();

MyRestClass.myMethod();
```

Comment: Agree with Adrian. I'd even take it a step further and extract the business logic out of the method so you can call the logic without needing an HttpRequest. It's by design that Salesforce doesn't allow call-outs from tests.

Comment: You don't need to extract it to a separate method to remove the need for an HttpRequest. You can call the method via Apex with no callout required.

Comment: Agree, you don't *have* to. updateStudentRoleRelationships gets roleIds and studentId from the request object. I would have an updateStudentRoleRelationships that takes roleIds and studentId as parameters which would be called by the @HttpPut method. Then it could be called from other places as well.